# AWS SES Sendmail stopped sending mail

Tags: amazon-ses

I setup my EC2 Instance with CentOS and Sendmail via SES over a year ago. All was tested & running fine for almost a year. But now for some reason all emails stopped being delivered.

The maillog shows the following:

```
Jul 17 11:11:12 tippingapplications sendmail[3808]: x6HI9YBG003808: from=admin@tippingapplications.com, size=106, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201907171809.x6HI9YBG003808@tippingapplications.com>, relay=root@localhost
Jul 17 11:11:12 tippingapplications sendmail[3815]: x6HIBCHK003815: from=<admin@tippingapplications.com>, size=372, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201907171809.x6HI9YBG003808@tippingapplications.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jul 17 11:11:12 tippingapplications sendmail[3808]: x6HI9YBG003808: to=barry.ralphs@gmail.com, delay=00:01:38, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30106, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (x6HIBCHK003815 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul 17 11:11:12 tippingapplications sendmail[3817]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx203.inbound-mx.org., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 17 11:11:13 tippingapplications sendmail[3817]: x6HIBCHK003815: to=<barry.ralphs@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120372, relay=mx203.inbound-mx.org. [198.133.158.249], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Queued!)
```

I don't see any messages being marked as delivered, rejected, bounced in my SES dashboard. My SES reputation dashboard shows healthy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These logs don't show SES is picture, the emails are relayed to 198.133.158.249.

Comment: I don't understand where that address is coming from. My 'access' file has: Connect:email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  RELAY

Comment: I was able to fix the issues by editing /etc/resolv.conf
I removed
search ec2.internal com
and added
search myDomain.com